# How to create a Linear and Logistic Regression Model in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have the following dataset

```
data <- data.frame(height=c(184,163,170,161,162,167,180,175,182,176,180,164,178,155,187,176,176,152,160,190),
                   weight=c(83,51,80,53,64,70,75,74,86,78,90,66,60,44,81,75,68,63,51,88),
                   shoe_size=c(44,37,42,35,38,40,43,42,44,43,45,40,40,35,44,40,42,39,36,45),
                   age=c(26,24,26,26,25,28,28,24,31,25,29,24,38,27,28,32,26,33,26,26))

hoodie = with(data, 
              ifelse(weight<=45, "XXS",
               ifelse(weight>45 & weight<=52, "XS",
                ifelse(weight>52 & weight<=57, "S",
                 ifelse(weight>57 & weight<=64, "M",
                  ifelse(weight>64 & weight<=75, "L", "XL"))))))

hoodie_data = cbind(hoodie, data)
```

I have to predict hoodie size i.e. S , M , L etc. based on my shoe size and weight
I try to do this

```
linear_model <- lm(hoodie ~ weight + shoe_size,data = hoodie_data)
```

It gives the error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

while using `as.factor()` or `as.numeric()` on hoodie, it returns NA

How to proceed?

Comment: Problem is that your hoodie column is perfectly predictable from the weight column. Adding both to your nodel leads to singularities. Deciding for one of both and dropping the other from the model should solve the issue.

Comment: you are looking for a classification model - try multinomial logistic regression (instead of linear regression; where response is numeric). i.e. `multinom` form `nnet`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. One is singularities as deschen mentioned. That is, there are perfect linear relationships between variables in `data`. See `cor()` below. The other problem is that you cannot use categorial variables (e.g., "S", "M", "L") directly as the dependent variable. You may use dummy coding or use number (e.g., 0 ~ 5) to represent hoodie size in this case.

```
data <- data.frame(height=c(184,163,170,161,162,167,180,175,182,176,180,164,178,155,187,176,176,152,160,190),
                   weight=c(83,51,80,53,64,70,75,74,86,78,90,66,60,44,81,75,68,63,51,88),
                   shoe_size=c(44,37,42,35,38,40,43,42,44,43,45,40,40,35,44,40,42,39,36,45),
                   age=c(26,24,26,26,25,28,28,24,31,25,29,24,38,27,28,32,26,33,26,26))

hoodie = with(data, 
              ifelse(weight<=45, 0,
                     ifelse(weight>45 & weight<=52, 1,
                            ifelse(weight>52 & weight<=57, 2,
                                   ifelse(weight>57 & weight<=64, 3,
                                          ifelse(weight>64 & weight<=75, 4, 5))))))

hoodie_data = cbind(hoodie, data)

cor(hoodie_data[, c(2:4)])
#              height    weight shoe_size
# height    1.0000000 0.8126724 0.8707172
# weight    0.8126724 1.0000000 0.9512942
# shoe_size 0.8707172 0.9512942 1.0000000

# use one of the independent variables
linear_model <- lm(hoodie ~ weight,data = hoodie_data)

summary(linear_model)
# ...
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) -4.056250   0.592073  -6.851 2.07e-06 ***
# weight       0.109375   0.008316  13.153 1.14e-10 ***
# ...
```